# After run sql file, Win10 MySQL CPU 100%

Tags: mysql

### Cause

After run a backed up sql file to my local computer, My computer cpu run 100%.
my steps:

1. before run sql file

```sql
/*avoid error DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled*/
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

2. create a new database
3. run a sql file (backed up in mysql 5.7.17) to import structure and data at this new database
4. import success;
5. 1 minute after successful import， win10 cpu usage 100%;
   screenshots:

[image: win10 cpu 100%]

### Version

1. win10 1909(18363.449)
2. MySQL 8.0.16

### Troubleshoot

```sql
show full processlist;
```

results:

[image: show full processlist]

```sql
show engine innodb status
```

results:

```
=====================================
2019-10-25 09:31:09 0x3d00 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 40 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 347 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 2245 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 316
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1781
RW-shared spins 799, rounds 800, OS waits 1
RW-excl spins 9658, rounds 25501, OS waits 212
RW-sx spins 8, rounds 172, OS waits 5
Spin rounds per wait: 1.00 RW-shared, 2.64 RW-excl, 21.50 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 371410743
Purge done for trx's n:o < 371410741 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 37
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 282782365114120, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365113248, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365112376, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365111504, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365110632, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365109760, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365108888, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365122840, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365118480, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 282782365108016, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: wait Windows aio (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: wait Windows aio (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: wait Windows aio (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: wait Windows aio (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
1980 OS file reads, 176203 OS file writes, 56718 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.67 writes/s, 0.42 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 462, seg size 464, 0 merges
merged operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 4 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 3 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 5 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.35 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          73725445734
Log buffer assigned up to    73725445734
Log buffer completed up to   73725445734
Log written up to            73725445734
Log flushed up to            73725445734
Added dirty pages up to      73725445734
Pages flushed up to          73725445734
Last checkpoint at           73725445734
136624 log i/o's done, 0.17 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137363456
Dictionary memory allocated 3671937
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       1024
Database pages     7147
Old database pages 2618
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 1763, not young 20320
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 1947, created 17850, written 33619
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.30 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7147, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[15]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=17416, Main thread ID=0000000000003E6C , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 142096, updated 54521, deleted 59578, read 563375
0.00 inserts/s, 0.10 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.40 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

#### Tried solutions

1. restart mysql service， no effect, after restart, cpu still 100%

```
net mysql stop
net mysql start
```

2. restart my computer,  no effect, after restart, cpu still 100%
3. show full processlist and kill some sleep or time cost most processes, no effect
4. show OPEN TABLES where In_use > 0; no results;
5. **delete this new database, everything is ok**,but this is useless

**Thank you so much to everyone who helped.**

Comment: Do you have any events in DB? Who is calling the ProvideUserId SP that is on screenshot?

Comment: @fifonik There are indeed events in execution.You have helped me a lot, I will check it out from this aspect.

Comment: Just looking at 2 lines of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

    Pages read 1947, created 17850, written 33619   AND  
    Number of rows inserted 142096, updated 54521, deleted 59578, read 563375  

- my guess would be something was in a never-ending loop.